# Getting text from .txt files to use as custom responseText?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm developing a simple photo upload system. At the moment, you can select a file, and when you click upload, a loading gif appears, along with a percentage uploaded. After upload is complete, an alert is shown with a message from an array that hold all the feedback messages.

However, I had to settle for an array after my preffered idea got me no-where.
IS there any way to use a .txt file as the responseText for my AJAX request? So say the text file said `Images Uploaded To Server`, how could I get that from the file, and display it in an alert after upload?

at the moment, this is the function called when upload is done...

```
xhr.addEventListener("load", function() { document.getElementById("loadingicon").style.display = "none"; 
    alert(message[0]); addIcon();} , false);
```

I've tried using `.open("GET", "text.txt", true);` , but I get an error `Undefined`.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#someButton").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "helloworld.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            success : function (data) {
                $("#textBox").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/